# Ember selecting from a list using click, command/control and shift keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a list of items, which is to be selected based on the below conditions. (like in the Mac Finder)

1. Click --> Select the current item and deselect the previously selected items.
2. Command/Control + Click --> Select the current item without deselecting the previously selected items.
3. Shift + Click -->  Select the item in between the items previously clicked and the current clicked item.

After selection,

1. I need to get the selected items.
2. I need to deselect all the selected items.

My Template:

```
<ul >
    {{#each}}
        {{#view App.TestView}}
          <li class="user">{{val}}</li>
        {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [{'val':'red', 'isActive': false},{'val':'blue', 'isActive': false},{'val':'green', 'isActive': false},{'val':'yellow', 'isActive': false},{'val':'orange', 'isActive': false},{'val':'pink', 'isActive': false}];
    },
    actions: {
        changeBgSelection: function (params) {
            var temp_obj =this.get("controller").objectAt(this.modelFor("index").indexOf(params));
            temp_obj.isActive=true;
        },
        deSelectAll: function(){
            this.get("controller").setEach("isActive", false);
        },
        getSelected: function(){
            //Get the selected items from the list
        },
        unSelectAll: function(){
            //To deselect all 
        }
    }
});  


App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNameBindings: ["isActive"],
    isActive: false,
    click: function(e) {  

        // Need to handle for click, control/command key + click , shift key + click. 

        // Need to call the method when an item is clicked 
        // this.get("controller").send("deSelectAll");
        this.set("isActive", !this.get("isActive"));
        var temp_model = this.get("context");
        this.get("controller").send("changeBgSelection", temp_model);
}
```

});

My JSBin [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ruvep/1/)

I could not make this happen as I am new to ember. I am learning and there is a lot to update, many thanks for your replies and help in any respect.

Comment: Code has to go in the question, not on JSBin.

Comment: @meagar Thanks I have added the code in the question.

Comment: I have found the solution and the link is available in JSBin --> http://jsbin.com/kocupegi/47/  also included Ctrl + A option to select all the list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long try I have found the flow and its working fine for all the selection conditon of the list. Additionally Ctrl + A selects all the items in the list.

JSBin [Link](http://jsbin.com/kocupegi/47)

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should just set the model on the view so you can actually reference it without having to pass the context back and have to search:

```
{{#view App.TestView model=this}}
   <li class="user">{{val}} - {{isActive}}</li>
{{/view}}
```

Then just add an alias to `isActive` and toggle that property.  Additionally you can just use `e.ctrlKey`, `e.shiftKey`, `e.metaKey` for finding out if the ctrl/shift/command is clicked.  I've included a small example to get you started.

```
App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNameBindings: ["isActive"],
  isActive: Ember.computed.alias('model.isActive'),
  click: function(e) {  
    if(e.ctrlKey) {
      this.toggleProperty("isActive");
    }else{
      this.get("controller").send("deSelectAll");
      this.toggleProperty("isActive");
    }
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/kocupegi/2/edit

Comment: @kingpin2k Thanks you very much for your answer. I will work with the above code and get back if I face any issues. While using ShiftKey I need to select the items in between the previous and current item clicked. I will check it out.

Comment: @kingpin2k After a long try I have completed all the use cases of selection. Additionally I have added Ctrl + A for selection all the list items. JSBin link is available here - http://jsbin.com/kocupegi/47/edit . Kindly check the same. Thanks a lot for your help.